# How to set up email forwarding system

Tags: email

We are a small company and we have many independent contractors working for us.  I would like to give each one of them a corporate email address such as firstname.lastname@mydomain.com.  I would like all emails to the corporate email address to forward to the contractor's personal email address.  I would also like the ability to view all emails sent to and from the corporate email address.

What is the best way to go about this?  I currently use Google Aps as our email solution.  Is it possible to do this with Google Aps, or should I set up my own mail server?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `I would also like the ability to view all emails sent to and from the corporate email address.`  I believe that's illegal.

Comment: @p.campbell: No idea.  Beliefs can cross international borders.  :)

Comment: Surely it's not illegal to view your employee's emails.

Comment: If you inform them, it might be legal. If you don't inform them, it probably isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with google apps. In the personal settings, a user can select the address(es) the end user want's its email to be forwarded to. The forwarder will work, once the recipient confirmed his secondary mailaddress.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I create a new Google Aps account for each user and set up forwarding for each of them?  If so, then I should explain that I am hoping to avoid that scenario since it would cost me an additional $50 per year per user.  Is there any other way to do it besides creating a new account for each user?

Comment: Not with google Apps. Run your own server then.